# Como tener una ventana flotante siempre al frente

Tags: javascript, html, css, ventana

Hice una ventana flotante a través de javascript estas son mis funciones:

```
<script>
    function abrir(){
        document.getElementById("vent").style.display="block";
    }
</script>

<script>
    function cerrar(){
    document.getElementById("vent").style.display="none";
    }
</script>
```

la ventana se muestra cuando doy clic en un enlace y de igual manera se cierra, el problema es que la ventana sale al fondo de los demás elementos de la página. ¿cómo puedo traerla al frente?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si esta ventana de la que hablas utilizas la propiedad `position: absolute`,
en ese caso podrias usar `z-index: 10` en tu archivo css o escribirlo por javascript (cosa que no te recomiendo) para que se mueste por encima de los demas elementos. Espero que te sirva